# Too Many Damn Buffalos

Tags: logical-deduction, word-problem, language

"Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo"

The sentence above is an actual sentence which makes perfect sense and is not wrong.
The word "Buffalo" has three meanings:

```
1) The City of Buffalo, New York
2) To buffalo (verb) to bully/intimidate
3) The animal Buffalo/bison
```

Can you explain what this sentence means?

Comment: Yes, we can. the capitalisation helps a bit.

Comment: It means "Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo". Correct?

Comment: Given that any sequence of *buffalo*s is grammatically correct there's a follow up question: What does *buffalo* repeated *n* times mean? (I mean for each *n* natural number) and more interesting, what's the meaning of an infinite sequence of *buffalo*s?

Comment: Am I wrong, or is the sentence meaningless without 2 commas? "Buffalo buffalo, Buffalo buffalo buffalo, buffalo Buffalo buffalo." Without those, it's not a proper sentence, is it?

Comment: Now count the number of consecutive "and" [here](http://www.sandraandwoo.com/2014/06/26/0593-buffalo-buffalo/) (though the sentence does not consist *only* of "and"s)

Comment: @mbm29414 commas would make it wrong. Consider "The cats your dogs harrass kill troublesome mice"—same sentence structure, no commas needed.

Comment: @Bakuriu Curious. You may however extend that to rational _n_ and then to real and complex ones... In fact, you might wonder what buffalo _times_ buffalo means

Comment: Is this really a puzzle? It sounds more like a general question about English...

Comment: Someone tell James and John about this nonsense, stat!

Comment: How this has so many upvotes is baffling me.

Comment: Related: [hads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_while_John_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_a_better_effect_on_the_teacher)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't really a puzzle, just an "explain this" question

Comment: Duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31163/how-should-i-parse-the-sentence-buffalo-buffalo-buffalo-buffalo-buffalo-buffalo

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Basically, it's "buffalo who reside in Buffalo, NY that bully other buffalo that also live there, also bully themselves."

Comment: Shouldn't it be "buffalo who reside in Buffalo, NY, *who have been bullied by other buffalo who also live there*, also themselves bully"? Otherwise, you're just saying "x and y implies y" which isn't that strong of a statement.

Comment: Not sure if the strength of the statement is what's in question here. It's a ridiculous sentence to begin with.

Comment: right, poorly phrased on my part…but I hope you take my meaning

Comment: I don't think this answer is quite right - the puzzle says nothing about bison bullying themselves, only that they bully bison (probably other bison).

Comment: This isn't as accurate as the answer below.

Answer (score 39):

[Wikipedia has a nice article on this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)

> Buffalo buffalo *(buffalo from Buffalo NY)* [that] Buffalo buffalo
>   buffalo *(that the buffalo from Buffalo NY bully)* buffalo Buffalo
>   buffalo *(are bullying buffalo from Buffalo NY)*.

[image]

Comment: Best answer by far.

Comment: @JoeZ. `B` and `b` are different graphs, though, and audio is not the same as spelling.

Comment: They represent the same letter with different capitalization, though. Is that really enough to distinguish them as graphemes?

Comment: (And I must correct myself; they are actually homophones, but they are *also* homographs.)

Comment: @JoeZ. Graphemes are the smallest units of writing. Latin capital letters are distinct and different from normal letters.

Comment: A quick Google says that a bunch of people consider capital and lowercase letters to be allographs, though...

Comment: @JoeZ. [Then how could they impart different meaning?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127507/why-is-the-christian-god-being-spelled-with-a-lowercase-letter)

Comment: Well even in phonology you have stuff like the [cot-caught merger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_low_back_vowels#Cot.E2.80.93caught_merger), where some people would consider "cot" and "caught" to be a minimal pair between [ɑ] and [ɔ], while others consider those two to be allophones and rely on context to provide the necessary information. I mean, you do have a point, it's not like the issue isn't up for debate.

Comment: @JoeZ. "othersounds" still refer to the same concept, but `Buffalo` is a different concept than `buffalo`.

Comment: Would you at least agree that the two lowercase "buffalo" (bison and bully) are homographs?

Comment: @JoeZ.: Depending upon whether one regards those words as rhymes, the number of verbs which rhyme with those words in at least one past tense form, *but do not rhyme in their present tense form*, is quite extraordinary.

Comment: Can you give a few examples? I'm not quite sure I understand what you're talking about.

Comment: @JoeZ. If they are written with the same symbols, as `buffalo` and `buffalo` are, then they are homographs. Homonyms are about names instead of symbols, so at least the first instance of `Buffalo` is one as it could refer to the city as well as the animal, or even the verb.

Comment: The picture clarifies it nicely.

Answer (score 18):

Let's replace the place with **New York**
Let's replace the verb with **bully**
Let's keep the animal as **buffalo**

Original:

```
Buffalo   buffalo  (that)  Buffalo   buffalo  buffalo  (also)  buffalo  Buffalo   buffalo.
```

Replaced:

```
New York  buffalo  (that)  New York  buffalo  bully    (also)  bully    New York  buffalo.
```

Comment: I don't understand how the sentence can stand without "that" and "also" being explicitly in the sentence. I understand it with them there, but as soon as they are removed, the sentence becomes nonsense to me.

Comment: @Michael Produce (that) farmers sell tends to be fresh.